# Was HTTP request received over TCP or UDP?

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee

Is there a way in Java to know if an `HTTP` request was received over `TCP` or over `UDP`?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/98951/does-https-use-tcp-or-udp for general `HTTP` information

Comment: Hi! I know `http` usually does not run over `udp`, but it does not mean it's not possible. And I was thinking that this could be a security issue. So I was wandering if it's even possible...

Comment: add code example, how you perform a request.

Comment: @Algosub There's no Java EE server that can do HTTP over UDP, so there's no means to check whether it's UDP  - it's always TCP.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I belive you can send a UDP request like it's show here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication, just replace the `MASSAGE` value to an `http` request.

Comment: @nos Are you sure? Can you point to a place where it's referenced?

Comment: ... Show me a server that listens to udp for http requests. You could send http over *anything*, that doesn't mean anything is *listening*.

Comment: @Algosub I'm sure. It's probably not referenced in any single place. The closest thing you'll find is the RFC for HTTP, which specifies TCP as the standard protocol, and would not allow the use of UDP since HTTP requires a reliable protocol. You would have to go and look through the features (or source code) of all the Java EE servers - you'll find that they do not do HTTP over UDP.

Comment: I think there's another, deeper question buried in this one.  Why do you want to check if the connection is UDP?  What are you trying to do that lead you down this rabbit hole?

Comment: @IanMcLaird lol... I'm a student in my first degree, and I just finished a course in information security, and it got me thinking about somethings. :)

Comment: HTTP is designed to not care about the underlying protocol very much.  It needs to be "reliable", but that's about it.  If it's not, you'd find your server sending a lot of `400: Bad Request` messages.  But swapping named pipes in for TCP/IP sockets shouldn't bother a program that operates on HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ceekay says, RFC tells that HTTP uses reliable transport only, so that means no way for UDP. But one may try to build some other protocol on top of UDP, or may be do not use TCP/IP stack at all..
But as your question is about Java, then the answer is - this is all about Java libraries and frameworks used. Actually all the libraries that I know, like HtmlUnit http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net for example, hide this information from you. So you are dealing with HTTP(s) only without knowing details about underground transport. But in theory this is possible that some library will show this information for you.

But actually I do not see a way why this may be importatnt for you (in 99.999999% HTTP will use TCP). If you tell us why you are asking that strange question, then maybe we will answer you more specific.

Answer (score 6):

Quote from the [RFC2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

> HTTP communication usually takes place over TCP/IP connections. The
>      default port is TCP 80 [19], but other ports can be used. This does
>      not preclude HTTP from being implemented on top of any other protocol
>      on the Internet, or on other networks. **HTTP only presumes a reliable
>      transport**; any protocol that provides such guarantees can be used;
>      the mapping of the HTTP/1.1 request and response structures onto the
>      transport data units of the protocol in question is outside the scope
>      of this specification.

I would say this eliminates default UDP. Other Reliable forms of protocols would still be possible